# Android: Real time android application design

Tags: android, real-time

I'd like you to help me to choose the right technology that fits my requirements with least costs.

The android app needs to constantly send the data back to server 
  (The data like heartbearts), as well as constantly receive the
  feedback data from server  (Real-time data, streaming)

The data type can be number, text, or even graph.

I'm now looking at three technologies

- MQTT
- stomp+orbited
- XAMPP

I'm not familiar with any of that, please give your suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realtime bi-direction full-duplex communication = [WebSockets](http://pusher.com/websockets).

IMHO WebSockets will become **the standard** for server <-> client communication. It's still *reasonably* early in their development, in terms of non-browser solutions, but the amount of options available to developers is increasing all the time. [jWebSockets](http://jwebsocket.org/) look like a good solution for Android and there are a host of WebSocket servers that are available to choose from. I work for [Pusher](http://pusher.com) who offer a hosted WebSocket service and there are other similar services that you can investigate.

Have a look at this [realtime technologies guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide) for a list of technologies (I'm trying to keep this up to date as much as possible as I find new technologies).

Comment: hey what would be the alternative if i donot want to use any third party resources on server side

Answer (score 2):

For Android native apps, there is Autobahn WebSockets for Android

https://github.com/oberstet/AutobahnAndroid

It supports the final RFC6455, integrates well with UI and service apps, provides RPC and PubSub over WebSockets, and more. Check out the project README on GitHub.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Autobahn.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at [Google Buffer Protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) - it was used in an application that I worked on and was extremely fast for data transfer.  It could be what you are looking for.

Comment: How can I use it in an android app? Is that possible?

Comment: Yup - have a look at this site : http://wweems.blogspot.com/2010/09/google-protocol-buffers-in-android.html